# VB script and chrome

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a lot of trouble modifying an existing website written in VB.NET.

Can someone please explain to me the basics to of the VB.NET-chrome relationship?

The specific problem I have is with sending mail through the website, I have no problem to add the relevant code, I just feel like I need to understand more before I start looking for bugs.

In the website there's an option to send an e-mail to a list of people. This option works in IE but doesn't work in firefox and chrome. I basically have a form tag which holds a table with a list of people with a check button next to every name. When you click send there's a function defined like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 

    Dim sTo As String, sFrom As String, sSubject As String, sBody As String
    Dim sCc As String, sBcc As String
    Dim MyMail As MailMessage = New MailMessage

    sFrom = "Laboratory Mail system sent from " & Session.Contents("UserNameEng") & " <dbsystem@mscc.huji.ac.il>"
    sTo = Trim(Request.Form("EmailTo")) & txtTo.Text
    sCc = Trim(Request.Form("EmailCc")) & txtCc.Text
    sSubject = Trim(txtSubject.Text)
    sBody = Trim(txtBody.Text)
    sBody = sBody.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br />") 'new

    MyMail.Headers.Add("Reply-To", Session.Contents("UserEmail"))
    MyMail.From = sFrom
    MyMail.To = sTo
    MyMail.Subject = sSubject
    MyMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html 'new
    'MyMail.Body = sBody
    Select Case optDirection.SelectedValue.ToString
        Case "BodyRtl"
            MyMail.Body = "<style> body {direction: rtl} </style>" & sBody
        Case "BodyLtr"
            MyMail.Body = "<style> body {direction: ltr} </style>" & sBody
    End Select
    ' MyMail.Body = "<style> body {direction: rtl} </style>" & sBody 'new
    ' MyMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-8-i")

    MyMail.Cc = sCc

    If chkCopyForMe.Checked Then
        MyMail.Bcc = Session.Contents("UserEmail")
    End If

    'MyMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
    Select Case optPriority.SelectedValue.ToString
        Case "Normal"
            MyMail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
        Case "High"
            MyMail.Priority = MailPriority.High
        Case "Low"
            MyMail.Priority = MailPriority.Low
    End Select

    If Trim(UploadFile.Value) <> vbNullString Then
        Dim myAttachment As New MailAttachment(GetAttachment(Trim(UploadFile.Value)))     '(Trim(UploadFile.Value)) 
        MyMail.Attachments.Add(myAttachment)
    End If

    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "pluto.mscc.huji.ac.il"
    Try
        SmtpMail.Send(MyMail)
        Response.Redirect("SentMessage.aspx?m=1")
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblComment.Text = "Problem With Sending Mail<br />" & ex.Message
        'Response.Redirect("SentMessage.aspx?m=2")
    End Try
End Sub
```

which is suppose to send the mail to the selected boxes. In IE the mail arrives, in chrome it doesn't.

Comment: How is VBScript being used? Client side? Server side? Windows scripting shell scripts?

Comment: To clear up the confusion: asp-classic used the vbscript language. asp.net does not use vbscript. It uses vb.net. Additionally, internet explorer supports a variant of vbscript in the browser that you can use instead of javascript, but no other browser does.

Comment: The code you posted is just an event handler. Does this get hit in both browsers when you debug? Are you getting any exceptions? Errors?

Comment: I think it doesn't get hit in chrome and firefox. No exceptions and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET is a server side technology - it outputs HTML to the browser.

The browser interacts with this HTML and may send responses to the server (clicking links, posting forms and such) - the VB.NET code can interpret these and respond with HTML.

This works the same way *regardless* of what browser (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera or any other).

Comment: In the website there's an option to send an e-mail to a list of people. This option works in IE but doesn't work in firefox and chrome. I basically have a form tag which holds a table with a list of people with a check button next to every name. When you click send there's a function defined like this
\n
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
\n
which is suppose to send the mail to the selected boxes. In IE the mail arrives, in chrome it doesn't.

Comment: @ZoharMeridor - Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add code to it.

Answer (score 0):

**This code has nothing to do with your problem.** The browser never sees it, only the server.

You've made a mistake somewhere **in your .aspx file**: IE is guessing correctly what you really want, and Chrome is not.

What happens with Firefox?

Comment: fire fox doesn't work as well.. I'll try to take another look at the code.